# Exchange shared calendar notifications

Tags: exchange, calendar, exchange-2010

We have an Exchange 2010 shared calendar that we use to keep track of when employees are OOO (Out of the Office). This calendar is shared out to our group & people will just put their time off directly on the calendar from Outlook. I need a way to notify certain business people when someone creates or changes events on this calendar. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this a public folder, or shared resource?

Comment: A shared resource.